# Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) returns wrong value in Setup project

Tags: c#, setup-project, deployment-project

I use VS2010 to create a setup project, I have a custom action which should create a file in *My Documents* folder.

But `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)` returns me an incorrect value. *My Documents* folder was redirected to another folder in *D:* drive.

When I test the custom action, I fount this method returns me an empty value, but it could return me a correct value in console applications, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Custom actions in VS setup projects that are being installed for Everyone run with the system account, not the account of the installing user.

If you want to create a file in that Documents folder, pass the PersonalFolder standard Windows Installer property into your custom action.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905(v=vs.85).aspx#system_folder_properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#system_folder_properties)

If it's a installer class call I think you'd pass it iss one of the calling argument in the form:

/mydocs=[PersonalFolder]

then use the dictionary key [arg] to get the actual resolved value (that's what [] means).